# PD_DF_NOT_CONTAIN

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Previous post was auto closed with a suggested resolution post that did not help. Trying to get the negative to execute properly given the DFs below. I need the IF to execute when something other than ONLINE is encountered in the STATUS column. With what is below, both IF statements execute when I'm intending for the second IF to execute.

Also tried (among many other syntax change attempts)

```
if sql_query_qa[sql_query_qa['Status'].str.contains('ONLINE').any() == False:
```

but does not work.

Any idea where I have it wrong?

```
if sql_query_prod['Status'].str.contains('ONLINE', na=False).any():
    print("\nA PRODUCTION DATABASE IS NOT ONLINE\n")
    status = ("A PRODUCTION DATABASE IS NOT ONLINE")
    email(status)

if sql_query_qa['Status'].str.contains('ONLINE', na=False).any():
    print("\nA STAGING DATABASE IS NOT ONLINE\n")
    status = ("A STAGING DATABASE IS NOT ONLINE")
    email(status)

Production

        DB  Status
0    FC_DB  ONLINE
1      AIM  ONLINE
2     WUDM  ONLINE
3  SCRPTSA  ONLINE

Staging

             DB   Status
0        TESTDB   ONLINE
1      AIM_TEST   ONLINE
2    FC_DB_TEST   ONLINE
3          WUDM   ONLINE
4  SCRPTSA_TEST   ONLINE
5       SCRPTSA   ONLINE
6        SAKILA  OFFLINE

A PRODUCTION DATABASE IS NOT ONLINE


A STAGING DATABASE IS NOT ONLINE
```

Comment: Both your dataframes have `ONLINE` in `Status` column, so both `if` are executed.

Comment: Yes you are correct, they are both executed. Sooo to my question, what do I have wrong? I only want the IF executed if there is a non ONLINE entry in the Status column.

Comment: Duh, it just clicked. Asking wrong question for what I posted.